# Describing interval $I_k$ in partition $P$ by their subintervals in the refinement partition $P'$ using union $I_k=\bigcup_{l=p_k}^{q_k}J_l$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-partition

**From the textbook:**

> Let
> $P=\left\{I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_n\right\},{\ }Q=\left\{J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_m\right\}$
> be partitions of $[a,b]$, where $Q$ is a refinement of $P$, so $m\geq n$.
> Since $Q$ is a refinement of $P$, each interval $I_k$ in $P$ is an almost disjoint union of intervals in $Q$, which we can write as $$I_k=\bigcup_{\ell=p_k}^{q_k} J_\ell$$ for some indices $p_k\le q_k$. If $p_k<q_k$, then $I_k$ is split into two or more smaller intervals in $Q$, and if $p_k=q_k$, then $I_k$ belongs to both $P$ and $Q$. Since the intervals are listed in order, we have $$p_1=1,{\ }p_{k+1}=q_k+1,{\ }q_n=m$$

If, for example, given an interval [0,1], a passable partition $P$ and refinement of $Q$ as
$$
P=\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{5}\right],\left[\frac{1}{5},1\right]\right\}
$$
$$ 
Q =\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{5}\right],\left[\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4}\right],\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}\right],\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right],\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right\}
$$

For $k=1$ we have the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{5}\right]$, then how $$I_{k=1}=\bigcup_{l=p_1}^{q_1}J_l$$ should work?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of $\;P'\;$ I'd use again $\;Q\;$ , as to refer to the original problem where $\;Q\;$ is a refinement of $\;P\;$ ... and to avoid adding more letters to the problem. and in this example  $\;I_1=J_1\;$ ...and btw $\;P\;$ is **not** a partition of $\;[0,1]\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio - I fixed it to .

Comment: @DonAntonio - Can you elaborate on why  is not a partition of [0,1]?

Comment: Because the union of the intervals in $\;P\;$ isn't equal to $\;[0,1]\;$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio - Oh, my bad.

Comment: Now it's fine...and as before: $\;I_1=J_1\;$, and of course $\;I_2=\bigcup_{k=2}^5 J_k\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio - Aren’t the endpoints  $0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}$ making $J_1\supset I_1$?

Comment: As far as I can see, 

$$\begin{cases}J_1=\left[0,\cfrac15\right]\,,\,\,J_{k+2}=\left[\cfrac1{5-k},\cfrac1{5-k-1}\right]\,,k=0,1,2,3\\{}\\I_1=\left[\cfrac0,\cfrac15\right]\,,\,\,I_2=\left[\cfrac15,1\right]\end{cases}$$ so trivially $\;I_1=J_1\implies I_1\subset J_i\;$ and also $\;J_1\subset I_1\;$ ....

Comment: @DonAntonio- But for some other examples, it didn't work this way. For example, in the same interval $[0,1]$ if $$P=\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right],\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right\}$$ and $$Q=\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right],\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right],\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right],\left[\frac{3}{2},1\right]\right\}$$ then
$$\;\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]=I_2=\bigcup_{k=2}^{4}{J_k=J_2}\cup J_3\cup J_4=\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{3}{2},1\right].$$
 This is clearly not trivial as before.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not trivial...so? What's your doubt here? Anyway, the interval $\;\left[\frac14,\,\frac12\right]\;$ doesn't belong in the last union...